# Ride7 UART0 Putchar Settings

Tags: c, arm, stdio, uart, stm32

I have been working on a project that uses an STM32F0 Discovery Board.  In this project I have plans on using the USART to send data to a computer.  I am aware that Ride7 has the required software to setup the stdio functions to work with the device.  I am unaware of how this works and what I need to do.  I set up the device to use USART1 for this purpose.  I looked into the setting and found the UART0 Putchar options.  It was my understanding that since I setup USART1 I do not want to use that so I set the option to no.  When I do this I get the following error:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Raisonance\Ride\Lib\ARM\smallprintf_thumb.a(_SP_puts.o): In function `puts':  
 _SP_puts.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `__io_putchar'  
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
  Error Code: 1 

Build failed
```

Swithcing the option to yes removes this error.

So my question is what does the UART0 putchar setting do?  Do I want on or off.  Additionally if all of this is handled by Ride7 do I even need to setup USART1?

Answer (score 0):

__io_putchar() must always be defined, so functions like printf can use it to output their characters string somewhere. But when you disable the UART0 putchar, you do not declare any replacement __io_putchar().

From the raisonnance Getting Started Guide :

> B) “include UART0 Putchar” 
>   This option adds “io_putchar.a” (or “io_putchar_thumb.a”), which includes standard putchar and 
>   getchar functions using the UART0. It should be used in conjunction with “UART0_stdio.h” 
>   (instead of “stdio.h”). It also redirects the output for functions using stdout, like printf, to the 
>   UART0. The “TEST” example shows how to use it. The sources of the library can be found in 
>   “C:\Program Files\Raisonance\Ride\LIB\ARM\IO_PUTCHAR\…” 
>   You can use and distribute them freely.

Check out the example in "C:\Program Files\Raisonance\Ride\lib\ARM\io_putchar", which shows how to write your own __io_putchar().

Write your own using UART1 and keep UART0 putchar disabled.